# Retrieving regex match from string and trimming other/special characters

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to retrieve compounds, contractions, or decimals from a line of text.

I've written regex for each:

```
contractions => ([a-zA-Z]+\'{1}[a-zA-Z]+)
```

YES: don't mm'nn m'n

NO: 't don' don'''t

```
decimal numbers => ([0-9]+\.{1}[0-9]+)
```

YES: 0.1 11.11

NO: .1 1. 1..0 m.n

```
compound => ([a-zA-Z]+\-{1}[a-zA-Z]+)
```

YES: twenty-six m-n

NO: twenty- -six twenty--six

What I'm doing is getting a paragraph contained in one String, splitting the string by white space so I get each word. Some words are **bolded** **like** **so** and some obviously have commas, and periods. at the end.

What I cannot figure out is before I store each word (which I'm storing in an inverted index to search later):

How do I remove all special characters from a String unless it matches any of those regexes above so that if I encounter "don't," I can store "don't", or if I encounter "*twenty-six*" I can store "twenty-six", or if I encounter "family," I can store "family" ?

Comment: What about contractions like `'tis` and possessives like `Jesus'`?

Comment: My professor did not specify such cases. It's hard enough for me to do what was specified, so I'd rather not account for 'tis and 'twas and possessives!

Comment: A regex such as `a` matches exactly one letter _a_; the use of braces can specify a range, such as `a{3,7}` which matches anywhere from 3 to 7 letters _a_ in a row.  Your use of `{1}` means to match exactly one of the preceding char, `a{1}` which is the same as the character specified by itself; the use of `{1}` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: [`(?:\s|^)(?!\w+-\w+|\w+'\w+|\d+\.\d+).*?\s`](https://regex101.com/r/DsbZRN/1) and replace with space:

```
String content = "put your string here";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\s|^)(?!\\w+-\\w+|\\w+'\\w+|\\d+\\.\\d+).*?\\s");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
String result = matcher.replaceAll(" ");
```

Also this will delete words like `family` because it didn't match any categories you mentionned, was that what you wanted?

I replaced `[a-zA-Z]` with `\w` and `[0-9]` with `\d`, it does the same thing but makes the regex more readable I think. Also you don't need the `{1}`, absence of quantifier is always considered as one.

---

**EDIT:** If you want to remove special characters not part of any category from the sentence: [`[^\w ]|(\w+-\w+|\w+'\w+|\d+\.\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/NHsCIK/2) and replace with `\1`

```
String content = "put your string here";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\w ]|(\\w+-\\w+|\\w+'\\w+|\\d+\\.\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
String result = matcher.replaceAll("\\1");
```

Comment: Thank you for the additions! And to be clear, I wanted to always get the string. So if it said "family," with the comma and didn't match those patterns, it would still return just "family" without the comma/special character.

Comment: Also, why did you add the .replaceAll(" "); Does it replace whatever doesn't match those categories with spaces?

Comment: Exactly. It's because the regex matches a space before and after the unwanted part, so no space is left, that's not what you want. I added a new regex to remove only special characters that are not part of one of your categories.

Comment: I tried your edit and it changes all special characters to 1 and also every occurrence of one of those categories to 1. So it recognizes the patterns, but I'm not smart enough to understand how to get it to save the string from the categories but keep the special categories? If that makes sense? :-)

Comment: Try replacing with `matcher.replaceAll(matcher.group(1));` maybe. If you want to match only special categories use `(\w+-\w+|\w+'\w+|\d+\.\d+)` to match them all.